# React Native Google Places Autocomplete API Session Tokens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I have a custom implementation of a Google Places Autocomplete in RN (that is I am not using this [library](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) and I have implemented my own `TextInput` and other components because I needed more customizability such as filtering the results and styling. Everything is working as expected. However, right now I am trying to figure out how to use google places session tokens which would prevent me from getting charged for every request (every single time the user types something in my component). However, all the resources I have found online refer to the use of session tokens in vanilla JS or react (web) where they use the following to generate a session token to be sent with the request as a param:
`const placesSessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();`

How I can mimic this in RN? My custom component uses an `axios` `GET` to retrieve the autocomplete results. My current understanding is that the earlier stated library handles session tokens by itself (although this is merely a guess because it is not really mentioned in the docs). I unfortunately could not find any answers really relevant to my case online. Any help would be much appreciated.